# E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 1165 (packagekitd)

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management

I am new to ubuntu and recently installed ubuntu 20.04 on my system.
At the time of installation, I was getting this error:
`PCIe bus error severity=corrected type=physical layer (receiver id)`
for encounter this problem I did:
Add pci=noaer at the end of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in the grub file.

Then my kern.log file was getting pretty big, as big that it was consuming the whole of my root
folder.
For this, I installed ubuntu using an internet connection. and this problem was also solved.

**Now on running `sudo apt update`  I am getting this error:**

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 1165 (packagekitd)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

I couldn't even remove this lock file; as my whole system will crash out,

May you please help me to encounter this error,
*I will be very much thankful to the whole of the community.*